# PHP Server for current Websocket Protocol in Google Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, websocket, phpwebsocket

Which Procotol uses Google Chrome 18 for WebSockets?

I need a PHP Server for this Protocol. I already tried Projects like php-websocket from nicokaiser or phpwebsocket from georgenava. But i got the same error twice (tried the demos):

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header is missing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the MDN WebSocket page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebSockets) and Chromium's [Web Platform Status page](http://www.chromium.org/developers/web-platform-status#TOC-Websockets), Chrome 16+ implements [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455)

Comment: Later versions of Chrome use later versions of the spec, up to and including [draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-17](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-17).  There aren't many interesting changes between drafts 10 and 17 but the Sec-WebSocket-Version header does change.

Comment: You're right, Simon. I've edited my answer to point to RFC 6455.